# Numerate jasmine tests

Tags: jasmine

Is there a way to automatically numerate "its"/"describes" in Jasmine tests?

It's really confusing when you need to include a lot of tests scripts (200+) and run them all at once from the same file.

And I'm trying to avoid manual numeration, for the obvious reasons.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why are you trying to number your tests? In BDD, the describe/its should be a unique way to name each test. I don't understand what numbering would give you?

Comment: It would give me an easier way to look for the tests which are failing. Tests are organized 'QUnit like', in modules, and I would like a quick overview of tests in each module. In the end, I ended up numerating them all manually, because I really needed that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a variable and incrementing it inside "it" description:

```
describe('EntityInfoComponent', () => {

   let testNum = 1;

   it('should be initialized #' + testNum++, () => {
       ...
   });

   it('should call service and show the results #' + testNum++, () => {
       ...
   });

});
```

Not a great method but it works. I've tried to inserting it on `beforeEach()` and `afterEach()` but it seems to be executed inside each iteration function code.

My answer has come 4 years later to this ask but I hope It'll be useful for future searches at least.